# Creating layers with different sizes from existing PNGS and imported into a PSD

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, transparency

Working on a legacy .NET web application we have the following issue: graphical themes are made of hundred `png` files. When it comes to create a new theme (ie. same icons but new set of colors), we take each `png` file and change its HUE using `paint.net`. It a very long process with poor results (images are pixelated, transparency is hugly...).

Using `Adobe Creative Cloud` we are trying to create a master PSD file that will contains all graphical elements. With well-named layers we will export them to individual files. We'll work with shapes and not "pixellated png" so changing color would be easy and clean. Moreover we will be able to change all icons' color in a row.

Icons aren't the same size and most of them doesn't "fit" content: for instance, one icon file is `27x27` with graphical content sized `13x18` at bottom right corner. Photoshop fits the layer to the graphical content: how to force it to a size of `27x27` and keep transparent content around the `13x18` painted area? Size can be `27x27` or `20x20` or `50x10` or ...

Answer (score 1):

Adobe just introduced an incredible feature called Adobe Generator that can do exactly what you are asking for (Adobe Photoshop CC only)

This includes:

- Real-time Image Asset Generation (save your PSDs and automatically update your folder of assets without manual saving)
- No slices necessary
- Use your named layers with customized variables for size, file-type, and transparency

It won't however:

- Adjust hues or add effects. I recommend chaining a Photoshop Action to generate your assets (e.g. have an adjustment layer be created on top of the layers and have the generator run after. then simply remove the adjustment layer)

Learn more [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/photoshopdotcom/2013/09/introducing-adobe-generator-for-photoshop-cc.html)

Also, if you want a tool for older versions of Photoshop, there is a great Mac tool called [Slicy](http://macrabbit.com/slicy/) that can do the same.

Comment: Generator’s a great suggestion for the exporting, but I don’t think it can help with the importing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to copy all the elements into one PSD then make slices for exporting in Photoshop. I would use [Texture Packer](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) to combine everything into one image automatically, but you'll have to make the slices by hand, which is pretty tedious, but there isn't a way to automate that as far as i know. After you have a PSD with slices you just apply different adjustment layers for hue.

You could make your production workflow a lot simpler by using CSS sprites instead of individual images, but you mentioned this being legacy, so maybe thats not an option.